# How to use lastIndexOf() function with symbols

Tags: javascript, html, character-encoding

Just started using `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()` functions and I know why they are used, however, the result doesn't make me feel happy :)

```js
let str = $('#info').html();

// WORKS
//alert(str.lastIndexOf('√'));

// DOESN'T WORK
alert(str.lastIndexOf('&#x0221A;'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info">&#x0221A;</div>
```

The problem is I get the alert result as "-1", which means the `&#x0221A;` couldn't be found in the `str` variable. Using simple symbol `√` it works, however, I'm not sure if it's a good practice using this symbol here.

In my opinion, another approach about this problem would be encoding `√` symbol in the HTML to `&#x0221A;`, so using "Inspect element" feature you would see `&#x0221A;`.

What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the browser reads and parses your HTML, it builds up a DOM, *without* retaining the exact HTML you provided. Later, if you ask for HTML, it builds a new HTML string using its own rules for doing that.

That's why `str.lastIndexOf('&#x0221A;')` doesn't work: The browser isn't under any obligation to give you back the character in the same form you used when you supplied it. It could give it back as just a character (`√`) or a named character reference (`&radic;` [in this case](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#named-character-references)) or a decimal numeric character reference (`&#8730;`), rather than the hex numeric character reference you're looking for.

You'll have to test on your target browsers to see what they give you, and then look for that. I suspect most if not all will return the actual character, and so your `str.lastIndexOf('√')` (or `str.lastIndexOf('\u221A')`) will be the way to go.

```html
<div>&radic;</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. What do you think, is using direct symbols like `√` is a good practice, it doesn't matter, or should I use `\u221A`?

Comment: @LukasNaujokaitis: It doesn't matter, do what you / your team prefer. Your stack needs to be set up correctly to ensure that the same encoding is used at all stages anyway. You only need to use `\u221A` if you're worried that you may have an encoding mismatch along the way. (You may prefer it as a matter of style, but that's the only reason you would *need* it.) But if you do, that's a problem to fix. :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I think using encoded strings is better because maybe in some browsers `\u221A` mapping works, but not the `√`. Of course, I'm talking about really old browsers. My whole JavaScript code wouldn't work there :D So, yeah, doesn't matter.

Answer (score 3):

There is no direct way to achieve this. But if you still want to do this way then you simply need to create a HEX value of the ASCII value:

```js
let str = ascii_to_hexa($('#info').html());
str = '&#x0'+str.toUpperCase()+';';

alert(str.lastIndexOf('&#x0221A;'));

function ascii_to_hexa(str)
{
  var arr1 = [];
  for (var n = 0, l = str.length; n < l; n ++){
    var hex = Number(str.charCodeAt(n)).toString(16);
    arr1.push(hex);
  }
  return arr1.join('');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="info">&#x0221A;</div>
```

Comment: Wow, such a long function only converting? :) Nice solution, however, it's very long for me.

Comment: Just added this answer so that it might be useful for you as well as someone seeking for same solution.